# Storing values of jQuery Mobile optgroup in SQLite

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

I have an optgroup like this for example:

```
<select id="opt1" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="left">
            <optgroup label="optgroup options" id = "opt">
                <option value="option1">Option1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option2</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
```

It is in the jQuery Mobile style and you can select multiple boxes.  I was wondering, once you select multiple boxes, it comes up as a list separated by commas on the select menu. Like:

option1, option2 (if both option1 and option2 are selected)

How would I then store option1 and option2 as separate values in my database?  For example if I had a column called "selectedoptions" how would I have it like this:

selectedoptions

option1
option2

rather than:

selectedoptions

option1, option2

in my database table

Hope this makes sense, any answers welcomed.

EDIT:  This is the code I'm using to store the multiselect values:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
               transaction.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable(Id, selectedoptions)\
                                      VALUES(1,?)',[$('#myoptgroup').val()],
                                      nullHandler,errorHandler);

               });
```

This returns my selected values like this: option1,option2 in my table row if both are selected as mentioned before.

Comment: Are you looking to create a separate row in the table for each selected option? If so, split the string on the comma character var optArray = $('#myoptgroup').val().split(",") and then iterate through the resulting array adding each one to the database.

Comment: Yes if both option1 and option2 are selected then I would like them to be stored on separate rows.  Thanks I'll have a look at split

Comment: Whenever I try to use this split method I get Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: val() is actually already returning an array not a comma delimited string. You just see the comma string when you look at the array in the debugger.  All you have to do is iterate the array: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lcbmh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multiple select element, the val() actually already returns an array of the selected values. You are seeing a comma delimited list because that is how the debugger displays arrays. So you can easily iterate the array like this:

```
var sel = $("#opt1").val();
for (var i=0; i< sel.length; i++){
    //create individual row here
    alert(sel[i]);
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Lcbmh/3/)**